# How do I stop getting my image streched in FileImage? [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-packages, pub.dev

I am using Flutter Custom Carousel Slider [Package Link](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_carousel_slider), I have a issue in `CarouselItem(...)` section where I cannot put `Image.file(...)` I want a image to be `fit: BoxFit.cover` but in FileImage there is no fit property and because of that my image get streched. How can I fix this issue? I tried putting Image.file instead of FileImage but it didnot work.

```
CustomCarouselSlider(
  items: List.generate(
    images.length,
    (index) => CarouselItem(
      image: FileImage(
        File(images[index].path),
      ),
      boxDecoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  height: size.height * 0.5,
  width: size.width,
  autoplay: false,
  showText: false,
  showSubBackground: false,
  indicatorShape: BoxShape.circle,
  indicatorPosition: IndicatorPosition.insidePicture,
  selectedDotColor: const Color(0XFFF9622E),
  unselectedDotColor: Colors.white,
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package doesn't have the option to change the `fit` property by default it is set to `fit: BoxFit.fill,`. You'll have to use any other package.

You can use other packages like [carousel_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider) or [flutter_carousel_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_carousel_widget) to achieve same functionality.